# push pop recenlty viewed session data with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, session

The following code it taken from a spree_recently_viewed gem

**Controller**

```
after_action :recently_viewed, only: :show

def recently_viewed
  id = @product.id
  rvp = (session['recently_viewed_products'] || '').split(', ')
  rvp.delete(id)
  rvp << id unless rvp.include?(id.to_s)
  rvp_max_count = 5
  rvp.delete_at(0) if rvp.size > rvp_max_count.to_i
  session['recently_viewed_products'] = rvp.join(', ')
end
```

**Helper**

```
module ProductsHelper
  def cached_recently_viewed_products_ids
   (session['recently_viewed_products'] || '').split(', ')
  end

  def cached_recently_viewed_products
    Product.find_by_array_of_ids(cached_recently_viewed_products_ids)
  end
end
```

**Model**

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
 def self.find_by_array_of_ids(ids)
   products = Product.where('id IN (?)', ids)
   ids.map { |id| products.detect { |product| product.id == id.to_i }    }.compact
 end
end
```

looking at this line in the controller

```
rvp.delete_at(0) if rvp.size > rvp_max_count.to_i
```

it is only replacing the value at index 0. Is there a way I can add push pop style so that when a new record is added value at 0 for example moves to 1 and 1 to 2 and so on and the last one gets poped out. and if already exist moves to index 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use array [`#unshift`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-unshift) method to push into the beginning of an array, and [`#shift`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-shift) to pop from the beginning of the array.

**PS:** According the whole controllers and models code. I don't know why both too comlpex... models method `::find..` can be simplified to just `Product.where('id IN (?)', ids)` or to `Product.where(id: ids)` (thanx to @bbozo) in the newer version of Rails.

Comment: Indeed, also `Product.where('id IN (?)', ids)` can be replaced by `Product.where(id: ids)`